# Mergefield Formatting

Tags: ms-word, mailmerge

How can I format my MERGEFIELD to show a suffix for Kilometers, i.e. "kms".

`{MERGEFIELD distance /# kms}` doesn't work. It results only in `kms` and omits the data.

Comment: If you always need the "kms", put it after the mergefield. If you don't always need the "kms", perhaps you could say more about when you do and when you don't. (Also, perhaps whether 1 Km needs special handling).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\#` switch is a numeric format switch that requires a formatting code in double quotation marks. Once the formatting code is in place, the additional text can be added in single quotation marks. As such, this code:

```
{ MERGEFIELD Distance \# "# 'kms' " }
```

will append "kms" to any raw number (no commas, decimal point, or other formatting). To see a comprehensive explanation of formatting field codes that includes additional formatting options, please refer to [Insert and format field codes in Word 2010](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-and-format-field-codes-in-word-2010-HA101830917.aspx#BM7) (or the equivalent article for other versions of Word).